# How to show a modeless dialog as an embedded fragment in small screen only using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css, oracle-jet

I have a requirement to show a modeless dialog with some content, differently in small and large screens. In large screens, it should open up as a normal dialog, but in small screens, it should become an embedded fragment within my main panel. Also, when screen rotates and if width changes from small to large, the embedded fragment should disappear and the popup should open up and vice versa.
This is for normal web development and i can use jquery and css.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are opening the dialog using some JS method, right? You can use OJET's ResponsiveUtils to detect screen size and decide if you want to open dialog or do something else:

```
   var smQuery = oj.ResponsiveUtils.getFrameworkQuery(oj.ResponsiveUtils.FRAMEWORK_QUERY_KEY.SM_ONLY);
   var smScreen = oj.ResponsiveKnockoutUtils.createMediaQueryObservable(smQuery);
   if(smScreen()){
     // open dialog
   } else {
     // show embedded 
   }
```

The exact logic depends on your code. The `smScreen` is observable so you can subscribe on it and in your HTML template you can display some content only if the `smScreen` is true or display the dialog....

Here are more details about the ResponsiveUtils in OJET http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/uiComponents-responsiveoptions-optionfwkquery.html

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. But in a 480*800 resolution device, if we rotate the device, resolution changes from small to medium. So i need to show the dialog. User might even be typing something in the dialog, while he rotates the device. So, i guess we need the embedded and the dialog open at the same time, but use media query to hide one of them.